# Why do I get the same value when printing this int?

Tags: c, gcc

So I'm just tinkering around with C and wanted to see if I could assign a binary value to an integer and use the printf() function to output either a signed or unsigned value.  But regardless I get the same output, I thought I'd get half the value for printing the signed compared to the unsigned.  I'm using Code::blocks and GCC.

Does printf() ignore the %i & %u and use the variable definition?

Sample Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    signed int iNumber = 0b1111111111111111;
    printf("Signed Int : %i\n", iNumber);
    printf("Unsigned Int : %u\n", iNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Same result if I change the int to unsigned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int iNumber = 0b1111111111111111;
    printf("Signed Int : %i\n", iNumber);
    printf("Unsigned Int : %u\n", iNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your int types are only 16 bits wide?

Comment: Note that binary constant syntax like `0b1111` is not ISO standard C.

Comment: Use a `uint16_t`/`int16_t` instead of an `int` so that you can make sure that you are filling up the entire value, including the sign bit.

Comment: Why don't you just do `signed int iNumber = -1`?

Comment: @Donotalo - My mistake, my scrap code didnt make sense, so when I pasted it for the posting I 'cleaned' it up so it was readable/made sense but I obviously overlooked a few 'minor' details  :)

Comment: @Jonh Bode - No I was just assuming ints were always 16 bits, I was working through a tutorial and it mentioned they were so I just ran with it.  From your comment I guess they can be larger, I'll search around and see what I can find on them.  Thank you!

Comment: @Professional, 16 bits is the *minimum* int size.  There is no maximum.

Answer (score 6):

I assume `charCount` should be `iNumber`.  Both programs have undefined behavior, since you're using the wrong conversion specifier once.

In practice (for most implementations), `printf` relies on you to tell it what to pop off the stack; this is necessary because it's a variable argument function.  [`va_arg`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdarg.h.html) takes the type to pop as the second parameter

The bits are the same between the programs before and after assignment.  So `printf` is pointing to the same bits with pointers of different types.

The reason you get the same result for `%i` and `%u` is that the leftmost bit is unset so it's interpreted as positive for both specifiers.

Finally, you should note that binary literals (`0b`) are a GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `0xFFFFFFFF` and `0x7FFFFFFF` (32 bit ints using standard C hex) and did get the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

Because for positive numbers, the binary representation on most platforms is the same between signed and unsigned.

Comment: <nitpicking> for positive numbers that fit in a signed integer (since other positive numbers are not representable as signed integers, thus their (non-existent) representation as signed integers cannot be the same as their representation as unsigned integers)</nitpicking> ;-)

Comment: In fact, apart from the above nitpick, the C standard requires this.

Answer (score 2):

First, you seem to be printing something called `charCount`, without error, and that `b` way of specifying a number isn't standard C.  I'd check to be sure it was doing what you think it is.  For a standard way of specifying bit patterns like that, use octal (number begins with a zero) or hex (number begins with a zero and `x`) formats.

Second, almost all computers have the same binary representation for a positive integer and its unsigned equivalent, so there will be no difference.  There will a difference if the number is negative, and that depends typically on the most significant bit.  Your `int`s could be of any size from 16 bits on up, although on a desktop, laptop, or server it's very probably 32, and almost certainly either 32 or 64.

Third, `printf()` knows nothing about the type of the data you pass to it.  When called, it is even incapable of knowing the sizes of its arguments, or how many there are.  It derives that from the format specifiers, and if those don't agree with the arguments passed there can be problems.  It's probably the worst thing about `printf()`.

Comment: Even for a negative number, he'll get the same results in practice, since assigning from signed to unsigned doesn't change the bit pattern on two's complement.

Comment: @Matthew:  Assuming he's printing the same bit pattern, he'll get different results for negative numbers, such as -1 and 65535 for signed and unsigned respectively for 16-bit all-bits-one in two's complement.  Assigning a negative number to a unsigned results in a large positive number, while I think assigning a large unsigned value to a signed is undefined.

Comment: I should have been clearer.  I meant the same between the two programs.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be different only for values higher than 0x7FFFFFFF as it is on almost all systems the bit with highest weight that is used to mark the sign. For faster computations inside the CPU, the other bits are reversed so 0xFFFFFFFF is -1 and 0x80000000 is -MAXINT-1 while 0x7FFFFFFF is MAXINT.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 32-bit ints. In this case, That means your iNumber has a value of 32767 regardless of whether it is signed or unsigned.